# How to install android SDK versions automatically on WSL1 with Ubuntu 20.04?

Tags: 20.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I am starting to use (and learn) WSL with Ubuntu 20.04, since I work with node and [cordova](https://cordova.apache.org/) apps I am trying to create a shell script that installs everything I need if (when) I break everything and I have to start from scratch.

I am installing the android skd using

```
sudo apt --assume-yes install android-sdk
```

and I add it to the PATH

```
PATH="$JAVA_HOME/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/tools:$ANDROID_HOME/tools/bin:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools:$PATH
```

Everything works great until there, now I need to install the android sdk versions, that the android developer site says to do using the [sdkmanager](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/sdkmanager) inside `$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools` but it is not there and I do not find any related package with it.

platform-tools content:

```
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root    512 Jun 30 11:08 ./
drwxr-xr-x 1 root root    512 Jun 30 11:08 ../
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 198984 Feb  8 11:55 adb*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  51312 Dec 13  2018 dmtracedump*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  22680 Mar 22 16:33 etc1tool*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 134160 Feb  8 11:55 fastboot*
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root root  14328 Oct 24  2018 hprof-conv*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     15 Aug 29  2019 make_f2fs -> /sbin/mkfs.f2fs*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     12 Aug 29  2019 mke2fs -> /sbin/mke2fs*
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     16 Aug 29  2019 mke2fs.conf -> /etc/mke2fs.conf
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root    923 Jun 27  2019 package.xml
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     16 Aug 29  2019 sload_f2fs -> /sbin/sload.f2fs*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root      7 Aug 29  2019 source.properties
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     20 Aug 29  2019 sqlite3 -> ../../../bin/sqlite3*
```

Inside `platforms` i see that `android-23` is there but nothing more.

Does anyone knows how to get the sdkmanager or the sdk versions??

Extra Info:

If I download the android command line tools manually, where to I put it? Should I delete the other things?

Answer (score 0):

I've not had much luck building from wsl, so here's my workaround:

In my `package.json` I have

```
  "scripts": {
    "start": "npm run remove:www && react-app-rewired start && node additions-build.js ",
    "build": "npm run remove:www && react-scripts build && node additions-build.js ",
    "build:cordova": "npm run build && node additions-cordova.js && mv build www",
    "build:android": "npm run build:cordova && cordova build android",
    "build:ios": "npm run build:cordova && cordova build ios",
    ...
    "test": "jest --runInBand --detectOpenHandles --forceExit --bail",
    "test:webserver": "cd build && ../node_modules/local-web-server/bin/cli.js --port 3000 --spa index.html",
    "debug": "node --debug-brk --inspect ./node_modules/.bin/jest -i",
    "eject": "npm run remove:www && react-scripts eject",
    "remove:www": "run-script-os",
    "remove:www:win32": "del /F www",
    "remove:www:darwin:linux": "rm -rf www",
    "remove:www:default": "del /F www"
  }
```

and to build my project from wsl I run

- `$ npm run build:cordova`
- `$ cordova build android` expect this to result in a failed build
- (you can condense the top two steps with `$ npm run build:android` if you want)
- open project in Android Studio
- build / export from Android Studio

On my mac I can do everything start to finish in cordova because everything is *nix friendly. Out of the box Ubuntu doesn't play nicely with windows binaries and I'm not spending time to wine my setup bc the whole cordova build process can change unexpectedly then it's back to ground zero.